# ERROR Failed to create job for config/connect-debezium-postgres.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:107)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, change-data-capture

I'm trying to do change data capture with Debezium using Postgres, Kafka, Kafka connect and debezium Postgres connector. Having an issue when trying to start Kafka Connect service with Debezium-Postgres-connector.

This is the plugin.path in my config/connect-standalone.properties:

```
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/connect/debezium-connector-postgres/
```

The connect-debezium-postgres.properties file:

```
name=first-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
database.hostname=postgres
database.port=5432
database.user=postgres
database.password=password
database.server.id=1
database.server.name=bankserver1
database.include.list=bank
table.inlcude.list=bank.holding
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=dbhistory.test
include.schema.changes=true
tombstones.on.delete=false
```

The command when starting Kafka Connect service with Debezium-Postgres-Connector:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-debezium-postgres.properties
```

The error Kafka Connect service:

```
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,571] ERROR Failed to create job for config/connect-debezium-postgres.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:107)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,581] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
A value is required
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:99)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:114)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
A value is required
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.maybeAddConfigErrors(AbstractHerder.java:691)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:207)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.lambda$null$0(StandaloneHerder.java:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,597] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:67) 
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,597] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:311)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,630] INFO Stopped http_8083@26be6ca7{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector:381)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,631] INFO node0 Stopped scavenging (org.eclipse.jetty.server.session:149)      
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,646] INFO REST server stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:328)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,646] INFO Herder stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:106)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,649] INFO Worker stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:199)        
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,650] INFO Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:66)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,650] INFO Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:659)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,651] INFO Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:663)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,651] INFO Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:669)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,652] INFO App info kafka.connect for 10.0.2.15:8083 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,652] INFO Worker stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:220)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,663] INFO Herder stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:124)
[2022-02-22 10:41:50,664] INFO Kafka Connect stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:7
```

[the content of the folders that put in the plugin path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIdbD.png)

Comment: Try just `plugin.path=/opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/connect` and make sure there are actual JARs within the `debezium-connector-postgres` folder

Comment: I have already changed the 'plugin.path' as suggested but unfortunately, Kafka connect stopped running. Maybe, I think the problem is the connect-debezium-postgres. properties file.

Comment: That file doesn't control what connectors are listed in `available connectors are: ` output. Can you show the content of the folders you've put in the plugin path?

Comment: already include a screenshot pic the content of the folders that I have put in the plugin path.

Comment: You've shown a targz file (which shouldn't be there) and just a folder, not the contents of **that** Debezium folder

Comment: already update the pic content of Debezium

Comment: When the Connect server starts, there will be logs about the plugin scanner. Do you see anything about Debezium there?

Comment: under the kafka/logs file there is connect.log file and the content of the connect.log file when it start to failed update on the post.

Comment: Alright, seems like you're missing a required property, and the connector doesn't start at all

Comment: Thank you for helping, already resolved the error now encountered the error regarding wal_level.